# Cannot dynamically create columns/rows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I want to be able to dynamically set a window's size in WPF, and then create as many columns and rows in a grid as I want.

I've created a method for it but it does not seem to work. I also added a border in XAML to see if there are columns and rows but I only see one square.
Also, it throws no error whatsoever.

This is my method:

```
public void CreateField(Grid MainGrid, TextBox Columns, TextBox Rows, TextBox WHeight, TextBox WWidth, MainWindow MainWindow)
{
    int ColumnCount = Int32.Parse(Columns.Text);
    int RowCount = Int32.Parse(Rows.Text);
    int WindowHeight = Int32.Parse(WHeight.Text);
    int WindowWidth = Int32.Parse(WWidth.Text);

    MainWindow.MainWindow1.Height = WindowHeight;
    MainWindow.MainWindow1.Width = WindowWidth;

    for(int a = 0; a <= ColumnCount; a++){
        ColumnDefinition c = new ColumnDefinition();
        c.Width = new GridLength(WindowWidth / ColumnCount, GridUnitType.Pixel);                
        MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);          
    }
    for (int a = 0; a <= RowCount; a++)
    {
        RowDefinition r = new RowDefinition();
        r.Height = new GridLength(WindowHeight / RowCount, GridUnitType.Pixel);
        MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
    }
}
```

In XAML I have this good with only 1 column and 1 row and a dockpanel for the textboxes and buttons.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
    <Grid Name="MainWindowGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Name="DockPanel"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Background="LightSalmon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="8">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Name="txtColums" Text="16"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtRows" Text="8"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtWindowHeight" Text="800"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtWindowWidth" Text="1600"/>
                <Button x:Name="ButtonCreate" Content="Create" Click="ButtonCreate_Click"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

[image]

And according to the parameters written here the method should be executed on button click. But instead of a grid with 16 columns and 8 rows, I only get 1 column 1 row. (you can see the border at the edge)

So what am I doing wrong here? I have no real experience with grids whatsoever, and I am pretty clueless. Hope someone can help me out.

[image]

EDIT:

*The suggestion of to activate MainGrid.ShowGridLines as said by ASh worked. Did not know about this functionality. As it turns out i do have succesfully created the columns and rows. I thought it not to work because i tried to paint a field in the grid with a color which did not work. Now i wonder, why this does not work as i thought this to be correct code.*

```
var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();
var brush1 = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFFF0");
DockPanel myDockPanel = new DockPanel();
Grid.SetColumn(myDockPanel, 3);
Grid.SetRow(myDockPanel, 3);
myDockPanel.Background = brush1;
```

Comment: it is an empty grid. how do you know that there are 1 row / 1 column? set `MainGrid.ShowGridLines=true;` to see exact layout

Comment: Try to color at least the background rather than white

Comment: @Ash thank you! :) But please look at my edit as well

Comment: @Ugur well if everything was to be blue i would have seen no differene either :)

Comment: @MansNotHot, again are you sure? #FFFFFFF0 is almost white. and it is on white background

Comment: @ASh yes definetily. I have changed the color to dark purple and nothing sadly.

Comment: @MansNotHot, add element to grid: `MainGrid.Children.Add(myDockPanel);`

Comment: @Ash Incredible thak you! Did not think that i needed to add it to the grid altough it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a lot going wrong here and its a magical jar of wonderment why you wanted to do this, however this should point you in a better direction

**Some Modifications**

- Dedicated `Grid`
- Get the `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth` to use
- Set `GridLines` `true`, so you can see whats happening
- Set the `Grid` alignments to `Stretch`
- Don't alter the size of the window

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="2">
        <DockPanel Grid.RowSpan="8" Background="LightSalmon">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Name="txtColums" Text="16" />
                <TextBox Name="txtRows" Text="8" />
                <TextBox Name="txtWindowHeight" Text="800" />
                <TextBox Name="txtWindowWidth" Text="1600" />
                <Button x:Name="ButtonCreate"
                        Click="ButtonCreate_OnClick"
                        Content="Create" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </Border>
    <Grid Name="MainWindowGrid"
          Grid.Row="1"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          ShowGridLines="True" />

</Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public void CreateField(Grid MainGrid, TextBox Columns, TextBox Rows) // TextBox WHeight, TextBox WWidth, MainWindow MainWindow)
{
   var ColumnCount = int.Parse(Columns.Text);
   var RowCount = int.Parse(Rows.Text);
   var width = MainGrid.ActualWidth;
   var height = MainGrid.ActualHeight;

   for (var a = 0; a <= ColumnCount; a++)
   {
      var c = new ColumnDefinition();
      c.Width = new GridLength(width / ColumnCount, GridUnitType.Pixel);
      MainGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(c);
   }
   for (var a = 0; a <= RowCount; a++)
   {
      var r = new RowDefinition();
      r.Height = new GridLength(height / RowCount, GridUnitType.Pixel);
      MainGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(r);
   }
}

private void ButtonCreate_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   CreateField(MainWindowGrid, txtColums, txtRows);
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer! helped a lot. but for clarification why are you against resizing the window in code?

Comment: @MansNotHot Not against , it just makes it easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

grid layout is correct. set `MainGrid.ShowGridLines=true;` to see it

to see dynamically created control you should add it to grid:

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(myDockPanel);
```

---

since grid rows have equal height and columns have equal width, the following lines can be safely removed:

```
r.Height = new GridLength(WindowHeight / RowCount, GridUnitType.Pixel);
c.Width = new GridLength(WindowWidth / ColumnCount, GridUnitType.Pixel);
```

if Width/Height is not set, it is defaulted to `*` which means Grid will size them equally.

as an alternative `UniformGrid` can be used:

```
AnotherMainGrid = new UnifromGrid {Rows = RowCount, Columns = ColumnCount };
```

but in this case child elements must be added consequtively